# how to remove all routes in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using renderDirections and requestDirections methods to create multiple routes called in a loop, now i want to clear them before calling that loop because even when there is no route data it shows that of past data.
PS: The methods are not called when no data is there but it shows previous routes

Below is my sample code to set routes:

```
 function renderDirections(result, Driver) {

        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ suppressMarkers: false,preserveViewport: true, polylineOptions: { strokeColor: colors[cur] } });
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        var leg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
        makeMarker(leg.start_location, Driver);
        makeMarker(leg.end_location, Driver);
        cur++;
    }
```

function requestDirections(start, end, wps, Driver) {

```
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        directionsService.route(
            {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: wps,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (result) {
                renderDirections(result, Driver);
            });
    }
```

Comment: directionsRenderer.setMap(null);

Comment: not working when deleting old routes

Comment: You create new instance of renderer each time when you call `renderDirections()`. Put initialization of renderer on global level and keep only one instance of `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()`. In this case `directionsRenderer.setMap(null); ` should work.

Comment: But to create multiple routes i need initialization of renderer each time

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your routes in an array, when you initialize it, like this: `routes.push (myRoute)` and next use the method `route.setMap ()` with the argument `null` to disappear them of the map. You can also remove them if you reset the array like this: `routes = [];` or `routes[2]=null` for one element. I give you some methods to remove or just disappear all routes.

```
// Sets the map on all routes in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        routes[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the routes from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}

// Shows any routes currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(map);
}

// Deletes all routes in the array by removing references to them.
function clearAllMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    routes = [];
}
```

Comment: okay.. as per the idea you gave, i made an array route[] and made them hold the Lat Long points of multiple routes. when the driver loop executes again after set time interval, i looped on route [] to delete route paths of old data but got error :  Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined ..  Plz guide

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: declaring directionsRender[] globally and setting up a counter to loop on old routes to clear it `

```
    function renderDirections(result, Driver) {
         directionsRenderer[cnt] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
         directionsRenderer[cnt].setMap(map);
         directionsRenderer[cnt].setDirections(result);
         cnt++;
    }`
      function clearRoutes() {  
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            directionsRenderer[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
```