# Update my google map after removing one of my "routes"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Developing a map with Google Maps API, I'm looking for a way to update my map after removing my "routes" in my "Service Directions" object:

```
(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes).splice(0, 1); //IT'S OK

//NOT UPDATE MY MAP :
directionsDisplay.setMap(null); 
(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes).setDirections(null);
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function in order to clear all routes:

```
function clearRoutes(directionDisplay) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        directionDisplay[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Consult the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) or this post in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281978/how-to-remove-all-routes-in-google-map).

*Tell me if you have some questions or some comments.*